# Printing with 1 mm nozzle keeps failing

Tags: print-quality, nozzle, elegoo-neptune-3

I'm printing a large print model, but it fails when I use a 1 mm nozzle. When I use the 0.4 mm nozzle, it works fine. What can cause a print to work with a smaller nozzle?

I'm using Cura as my slicer and Neptune 3 Pro (Klipper) as my printer.

Here are screenshots of my Cura settings, 3D model, and one of many failed prints:

[image]

[image]
https://photos.app.goo.gl/M1xSF5hEZ3zaiKti8

Comment: Hi and welcome. It is better to upload your photos into the question, using the editing tool, rather than provide an external link. People are less likely to click on an external link.

Comment: @amb1s1 For this you need to reduce the speed for printing, try to use 60mm/s but recomended is 50. the temperature seems ok, however if you need a fast print, you may need to increase the temperature to 220. infill speed 60mm/s. My printer has an upgrade to use a large throat nozzle.

Comment: @FernandoBaltazar Please don't answer in comments.  Instead, write an answer that can be voted up or down.

Answer (score 2):

A cursory inspection of your settings shows that you are printing at 75 mm/s and 210 ℃.

If you were printing with a 0.4 mm nozzle and a 0.2 mm layer height, the flow rate will be 75 x 0.4 x 0.2 = 6 mm<sup>3</sup>/s, which is well within the capabilities of a stock MK8 hot end.

However, if you print with a 1 mm nozzle and 0.7 mm layer height, the flow rate will be 75 x 1.0 x 0.7 = 52.5 mm<sup>3</sup>/s, which is well outside a stock hot end's capabilities.

You could try raising the printing temperature and lowering the printing speed, but frankly, a 1 mm nozzle is not really suitable for most FDM printers. A 0.6 mm nozzle should be eminently usable, and you may be able to get away with a 0.8 mm nozzle, if you are prepared to use lower printing speeds.

Comment: 1mm nozzle is fine if you're happy with chonky layers; I've seen folks use even larger ones. The OP's problem is just having configured speed that produces an impossible flow rate. Slicers should really be working in flow rates not positional speeds.